# clone private git repo inside ec2 instance with terraform

Tags: git, amazon-ec2, gitlab, terraform

I Created an ec2 instance with terraform and I want to know how to clone a private git repo in the created instance using terraform

Comment: TF is great for creating infrastructure, but not the best at code deployment.

Comment: What do you recommand me to use to deploy my code after deploying the instance ?

Answer (score 0):

I created a key pair on a Linux ec2 instance manually.  I then saved the private key as a Terraform Cloud variable (marked as sensitive) with the public key in the git repo under access keys(BitBucket).  I was then able to use template files and the user_data section to re-create the private key part on the ec2 instance, add it to the ssh-agent and also clone the repo.

From the runcmd array:

```
...
    "echo \"${local.ssh_private_key_file}\" > home/${local.ec2_user}/.ssh/${local.ssh_keypair_file_name}",
    "chmod 600 /home/${local.ec2_user}/.ssh/${local.ssh_keypair_file_name}",
    "eval \"$(ssh-agent)\"",
    "ssh-add /home/${local.ec2_user}/.ssh/${local.ssh_keypair_file_name}",
    "cd folder_to_put_code",
    "git clone path_to_repo",
...
```

After the ec2 instance is built and the code is updated:

- You could run the terraform apply command to rebuild the machine with the updated code.
- Or create a pipeline that is triggered on merging of the master branch to push the code to the ec2 instance.
- Or log into the ec2 instance and do a git pull